# How did Lanczos find his approximation for the Gamma function?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, algorithms, gamma-function

The Lanczos approximation gives a fixed-precision method for calculating the Gamma function. It is used in Desmos in their factorial function.

According to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation), Lanczos derived his approximation of the Gamma function by rewriting its defining integral,
$$\Gamma(z+1)=\int_0^{\infty}t^ze^{-t}dt$$Into the following form:

$$= (z + g + 1)^{z+1}e^{-(z+g+1)}
\int_0^e \Big( v \left( 1-\log{v} \right) \Big)^zv^gdv$$

He then found a series representation for the integral in this expression.

What kind of substitution would you have to use to get this form of the integral? Moreover, where did the constant $g$ come from, and what motivated Lanczos to include this constant in his formula? Finally, how could you derive a series expansion for this integral?

---

**EDIT**

@Kstargamer gave me a hint to help with the first part of this problem, the rewriting of the Gamma function. It only requires a couple of substitutions.

Start with the substitution $t = u(z+g+1) \iff dt=(z+g+1)du$. The limits of integration remain the same. This gives:
$$\Gamma(z+1)=\int_0^{\infty} (u(z+g+1))^ze^{-u(z+g+1)} (z+g+1) \,du
\\ = (z+g+1)^{z+1} \int_0^{\infty} u^ze^{-u(z+g+1)} \,du
$$

Next, substitute $u = 1-\log{v} \iff v = e^{1-u}, du = -\frac{dv}{v}$. As $u \to 0, v \to e$. As $u \to \infty, v \to 0$. This gives:
$$\Gamma(z+1) = (z+g+1)^{z+1} \int_e^0 (1-\log{v})^z \left(\frac{v}{e}\right)^{z+g+1}\frac{-dv}{v}
\\ = (z+g+1)^{z+1}e^{-(z+g+1)} \int_0^e (1-\log{v})^z v^{z+g}\, dv
\\ \therefore \Gamma(z+1) = (z+g+1)^{z+1}e^{-(z+g+1)} \int_0^e \Big(v(1-\log{v})\Big)^z v^g\, dv
$$

And with that, we have the simple manipulations that give the integral that Lanczos used.

However, this does *not* close the question. I’m still looking for a way to derive the series expansion for this integral that Lanczos used. I’m open to ANY suggestions as to how to find this.

Comment: Apparently $g$ can be arbitrary... weird

Comment: Take $1-\log v = u$ then we arrive at $$\int_{1}^{\infty} (g+z+1)^{z+1}u^z e^{-u(g+z+1)} \, du$$ and proceed with some manipulation.

Comment: @KStarGamer Thank you! I’ll edit this note into my question. I’m still curious about where the full series expansion comes from, though. (P.S., that lower limit should be 0).

Comment: @Mailbox Yes you are correct, that should be $0$, that was a typo from me oops. The series expansion comes from using a Fourier series as far as I’m aware. See page $11$ of [this paper](https://web.viu.ca/pughg/phdThesis/phdThesis.pdf#110).

Comment: That is an extremely useful paper.